# How to get thumbnail with pure PHP in a Wordpress database?

Tags: php, query

I need help to get thumbnails in a WordPress database with pure PHP because a need insert this in a Magento Application (Feed). Can someone help me?

I need this:

> http://luckifas.nextmp.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/fashionista_web_header_by_lstar92-d3gkahi-263x130.jpg

or part of this, example:

- /uploads/2015/09/fashionista_web_header_by_lstar92-d3gkahi-263x130.jpg
- /2015/09/fashionista_web_header_by_lstar92-d3gkahi-263x130.jpg

More details:

```
add_image_size('magento-image', 263, 130, true);
```

PHP Script used:

```
function SimpleLoopWordpress (){

    try {

        // PDO em ação!
        $pdo = new PDO ( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=", "", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date ASC";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $i = 1;
        echo '<div class="row">';

        while ( $linha = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) {

            ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <?php 
                         echo $i++;
                         echo FEATURED IMAGE <--------
                         echo $linha->post_title;
                         echo $linha->post_date;
                         echo $linha->post_content;
                    ?>  
                </div>

            <?php

        }

        echo '</div>';

    }
```

> I posted completly updated php script in pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/49Mbj484

- So far this point it's ok ---> `$meta->execute( $linha->thumbnail_id ); // ids 15 - 16`

**Thanks**

Comment: Do you need the file path or URL, or both?

Comment: Do you have the post ID to work with in your Magento app?

Comment: I have a loop for get others infos but not FEATURED IMAGE. I posted the script.

Comment: I have updated question and posted complete script in pastebin. I'm not php erros and I'm not image :(

Comment: Can you help me out then by 1) ensuring PHP error reporting is on 2) debugging some variables with `print_r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, a couple of things - first I would suggest modifying your main query to grab the thumbnail ID at the same time (I have also changed it to only get posts that *have* a thumb):

```
$sql = "SELECT wp_posts.*, meta_value AS thumbnail_id FROM wp_posts " .
       "LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id " .
       "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND meta_value != '' " .
       "ORDER BY post_date ASC";
```

Now for the processing:

```
while ( $linha = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) {

    $meta = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "_wp_attachment_metadata" AND post_id = ?' );
    $meta->execute( array( $linha->thumbnail_id ) );

    $file = null; // Failsafe in case anything below fails
    if ( $data = $meta->fetchColumn() ) {
        if ( $data =@ unserialize( $data ) ) {
            $file = $data['file'];

            if ( ! empty( $data['sizes'] ) ) {
                $sizes = $data['sizes'];

                if ( ! empty( $sizes['magento-image'] ) )
                    $file = $sizes['magento-image']['file'];
                elseif ( ! empty( $sizes['thumbnail'] ) ) // You might want to fallback, up to you
                    $file = $sizes['thumbnail']['file'];
            }

            if ( $file !== $data['file'] ) {
                // Files stored in sizes are only the basename
                // If you use year/month uploads, we need to grab that path

                if ( '.' !== $path = dirname( $data['file'] ) )
                    $file = "$path/$file";
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $file ) {
        // Gotcha!
        echo "<img src='http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/$file' />";
    }

}
```

This code is not tested, so see how you go and report back with any errors.

Comment: **if ( $data = $meta->fetchColumn() ) {** <- problem here ...

Comment: This if return **false** ... sorry my english :)

Comment: Meta execute line was wrong, argument should be an array (see revision)

Comment: **var_dump($meta->fetchColumn());** return **bool(false) bool(false)**

Comment: Owwwwwwwwwwwwwwww you are very very the best programmer man I encountered in this community. Very very very good man !!!!